# JQuery: Mouse move event?

Tags: jquery

I know that I can track when the mouse is moved like this:

```
$("body").mousemove( function(e){
    alert( "You moved to WIDTH " + e.pageX );
} );
```

Ok. I wanna be able to tell whether the mouse pointer was moved to left or to the right.

I know that to do this, I'll have to know the previous mouse position and simply compare it to the current. But how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var prevX = 0;
$(window).mousemove(function(e) {
    $("div").text(prevX >= e.pageX ? "left" : "right");
    prevX = e.pageX;
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tb86F/

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>var pos=0;
$("body").mousemove( function(e){
    if(pos<e.pageX)
    alert( "You moved to RIGHT" );
else alert("oved to left");
    pos=e.pageX;

} );
```